# Delay time when exposing in Xlib

Tags: gcc, xlib, timedelay

I'm trying to work out a time-delay to display steady flickering. I didn't get it to work with `sleep()` or `time.h`, what seems to be logically.

How could I achieve something like, displaying a white rectangle for 10 seconds, then clear this area (also for 10 sec), in a loop.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871071/x11-how-to-delay-repainting-until-all-events-are-processed), a `socket of the X11 connection` is mentioned to do things like that. But where to dig in, in this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file descriptor is in the Display structure and can be obtained with the macro `ConnectionNumber(dis)`.

You could then use `poll` with a timeout to wait for an event to arrive or a timeout to occur.

As mentioned in the other questions, `XPending` will let you see if there are any events, so you don't actually need to check the file descriptor, you could do something like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() 
{
    XEvent ev;
    Display *dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dis, RootWindow(dis, 0), 1, 1, 500, 500, 0, BlackPixel (dis, 0), WhitePixel(dis, 0));
    XMapWindow(dis, win);
    GC gc = XCreateGC(dis, win, 0, 0);
    int draw = 1;
    time_t t = time(NULL) + 10;

    XMapWindow(dis, win);

    XSelectInput(dis, win, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);

    while (1)  
    {
        if (XPending(dis) > 0)
        {
            XNextEvent(dis, &ev);
            switch  (ev.type) 
            {
                case Expose:   
                printf("Exposed.\n");
                    if (draw > 0)
                {
                    XFillRectangle(dis, win, gc, 100, 100, 300, 300);
                }
                break;

                case KeyPress:
                printf("KeyPress\n");
                /* Close the program if q is pressed.*/
                if (XLookupKeysym(&ev.xkey, 0) == XK_q) 
                    {
                    exit(0);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Pending\n");
            sleep(1);
            if (time(NULL) >= t)
            {
                /* Force an exposure */
            XClearArea(dis, win, 100, 100, 300, 300, True);
            t += 10;
            draw = 1 - draw;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: you might want to use something like `usleep` to get a finer timer granularity.

Comment: hi, actually my computer is much to bad to get it done smoothly with Xlib I think (I tried it with usleep - always some recognizable irregular latency ). And There is always depending on the x11 display managing routines. Maybe i'll try working directly with my gfx card if I can achieve it.